# kubernetes: Authentication to ui with default config file fails

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

I have successfully set up a kubernetes cluster on AWS using `kops` and the following commands:

```
$ kops create cluster --name=<my_cluster_name> --state=s3://<my-state-bucket> --zones=eu-west-1a --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.small --dns-zone=<my-cluster-dns>

$ kops update cluster <my-cluster-name> --yes
```

When accessing the dashboard, I am prompted to either enter a token or

> Please select the kubeconfig file that you have created to configure access to the cluster.

When creating the cluster, `~/.kube/config` was created that has the following form:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 
    <some_key_or_token_here>
    server: https://api.<my_cluster_url>
  name: <my_cluster_name>
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: <my_cluster_name>
    user: <my_cluster_name>
  name: <my_cluster_name>
current-context: <my_cluster_name>
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: <my_cluster_name>
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    client-certificate-data:
    <some_key_or_certificate>
    client-key-data:
    <some_key_or_certificate>
    password: <password>
    username: admin
- name:<my-cluster-url>-basic-auth
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    password: <password>
    username: admin
```

Why when pointing the kubernetes ui to the above file, I get

> Authentication failed. Please try again.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the same and had the same problem. It turns out that kops creates a certificate based authentication. Certificate based authentication can't be used on the web UI interface. Instead, I tried using the token based authentication. Next question, where do you find the token?

```
kubectl describe secret
```

This will show you the default token for the cluster. I assume this is very bad security practice but if you're using the UI to improve your learning and understanding then it will get you moving in the right direction.

[This Dashboard wiki page is about authentication.](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control) That's where I discovered how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable basic auth in Dashboard `--authentication-mode=basic` flag has to be provided. By default it is set to `--authentication-mode=token`

To get the token or understand more about access control please refer [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control)

Comment: The `--authentication-mode=basic` flag is used when?

Comment: in your kube-api configurations

Comment: Sorry, but I'm newbie.
where can i found the  kube-api configurations?
Do I need call some  command in kubectl?

Comment: This answer is not helpful basically you are saying RTFM.